# I use webpack for my amd style js, then generate two files "bundle.js" and "1.bundle.js", why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I use the command
`webpack app.js bundle.js`

app.js:

```
cats = require('./cats.js');
console.log(cats);
```

that will only generate one file, 'bundle.js'.

If I change it to a amd style:

```
cats = require(['./cats.js']);
console.log(cats);
```

that will generate two files, 'bundle.js' and '1.bundle.js'.

So, why ?

Comment: Probably because bundle.js will load only by demand the 1.bundle.js.  This is the AMD way.